# Grouping data and sort by by another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pandas-groupby

I want to group my data by one column and sort it by another. For sample data below:

```
df = {'Features':['A','A','A','C','C','C','C','B','B','B'],'Date':['1/3/2023','1/3/2022','1/3/2021','1/3/2024','5/8/2020','5/8/2021','5/8/2022','6/1/2020','6/1/2019','5/8/2023'],'Value':[7,8,2,6,8,9,8,9,0,10]}
pd.DataFrame(df)

Features    Date    Value
0   A   1/3/2023    7
1   A   1/3/2022    8
2   A   1/3/2021    2
3   C   1/3/2024    6
4   C   5/8/2020    8
5   C   5/8/2021    9
6   C   5/8/2022    8
7   B   6/1/2020    9
8   B   6/1/2019    0
9   B   5/8/2023    10
```

I want to group the data by Features and sort by Value column.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: `df.sort_values(['Features', 'Value'])`

Comment: Or [`df.groupby('Features')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)